Different collinearity treatment across R ad Stata
I have un unbalanced panel dataset of 59 panel units. Data frequency is quarterly and my sample includes 10 years of data. Missing data are left missing (no imputation). My main regression model includes 5 bank-specific control variables (of which 3 are of main interest), 1 crisis dummy variable, 3 interaction terms for the 3 independent variables of interest (interacted with the crisis dummy), 3 macroeconomic control variables, time-fixed effects and bank fixed effects. Troughout the regressions, I use clustered standard errors (at the bank level). This regression is runned smoothly in Stata. However, in R, the crisis dummy together with the VSTOXX variable (1 of the 3 macroeconomic control) are omitted because of collinearity. Would you have an idea of why this happens and differs across R and Stata? If I print the correlation matrix, for the Crisis Dummy I get NA for its correlation with all the other variables (but I guess this is normal given the dummy takes value of 0 in good times and of 1 in bad times). I thank you in advance for your help.
STATA CODE
xtreg Y X1 X2 X3 Crisis.Dummy X1.crisis_lag X2.crisis_lag X3.crisis_lag Log_X4_lag X5_lag VSTOXX_lag deltaIR_lag deltaCTGDP_lag i.quarter, fe vce(cluster id)
R CODE
model_winsor <- plm(Y ~ X1_lag + X2_lag + X3_lag + Crisis.Dummy + X1.crisis_lag + X2.crisis_lag + X3.crisis_lag + Log_X4_lag + X5_lag + VSTOXX_lag + deltaIR_lag + deltaCTGDP_lag, data = df_complete_panel, model = "within", effect = "twoways") 
robust_se_winsor <- vcovHC(model_winsor, type = "HC1", cluster = "group")


Welcome to CV, Maurizio. If you don't tell the software which redundant variables to remove, how is it supposed to decide?  The answer is arbitrary.

Hello @whuber. Thank you. Maybe I explained myself not in the most correct way. In Stata I run my main model with no problems. When I move to R and try to replicate my results also with R, then the software tells me that VSTOXX and the crisis dummy are omitted because of collinearity. This is not the case in Stata. I wonder why do I register this discrepancy across the two software. If one omits, also the other should.

Can you add the commands? There are so many ways to run panel regression models.

model_winsor <- plm(Y ~ X1_lag + X2_lag + X3_lag + Crisis.Dummy +
X1.crisis_lag + X2.crisis_lag + X3.crisis_lag +
Log_X4_lag + X5_lag +
VSTOXX_lag + deltaIR_lag + deltaCTGDP_lag,
data = df_complete_panel,
model = "within",
effect = "twoways")
robust_se_winsor <- vcovHC(model_winsor, type = "HC1", cluster = "group")

Does Stata fit an intercept?

Include the Stata code too. Add both R and Stata to the post by editing.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Yes, Stata does fit the intercept.

One thing we have learned about diagnosing discrepancies between software platforms is to carefully and thoroughly verify that both calculations are working with exactly the same data.  Have you done that?  It will help to reduce your example to a minimal reproducible one.  You certainly don't need so many variables to elicit this problem and, with fewer variables, you likely don't need many observations, either.

Apparently, R treates time fixed-effects differently from Stata (with less flexibility). Vstoxx and the crisis dummy are omitted due to collinearity with time fixed-effects.
